# has-popup="true" on <li> or <a>?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a menu that's written like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li aria-haspopup="true">
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul aria-label="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
```

I tested my site with the accessibility audit checker on accessibe.com and I was pulled that my submenu did not have `aria-haspopup="true"` on it.

My question is, should that attribute be on the `<li>` or `<a>`?

My thought is that it is the `<li>` that activates the hover menu on hover and on focus with both mouse and keyboard. Not the `<a>`. If this is correct then why is the  getting flagged for not having it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert on accessibility, but I did some reading and I hope this can help.

[Fly-out Menus - WAI Web Accessibility Tutorials](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/) has basically the same submenu structure as your code and puts the `aria-haspopup` attribute on the `<a>` element:

```html
<nav aria-label="Main Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="…">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="…">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="…" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Space Bears
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="…">Space Bear 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="…">Space Bear 6 Plus</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="…">Mars Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="…">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Why did not your code pass the audit checker? I cannot know for sure as I do not have access to it, but my guess would be that it is because the `<li>` element is not by default keyboard accessible.

> For the popup element to be keyboard accessible, authors **SHOULD** ensure that the element that can trigger the popup is focusable, that there is a keyboard mechanism for opening the popup, and that the popup element manages focus of all its descendants as described in [Managing Focus](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#managingfocus).
>
> -- [Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#desc-aria-haspopup:%7E:text=For%20the%20popup%20element%20to%20be,descendants%20as%20described%20in%20Managing%20Focus.)

I hope some expert chimes in and lets us know for sure.

Comment: Many thanks.  The fact that an <a> is focusable and an <li> is not makes perfect sense.   Just a little annoying considering this is a purely CSS activated dropdown therefore the <li> is the item that triggers it in my case.

Comment: @rctneil there is not really a way to achieve a fully accessible dropdown without JavaScript as you need to toggle the `aria-expanded` property. Also if you have your selectors on the `<li>` how are you handling focus indicators for keyboard users, are you using `focus-within`? As then you would need to use a polyfill for browsers that don't support it (namely IE) as a lot of assistive tech users still use IE (about 4.4%!). I would say change your trigger to the anchors instead, it will make your life a lot easier from an accessibility perspective.